# Can a USB type-C PD port of a laptop provide high voltage?

Tags: usb-c, usb-pd

I have designed a MCU board using [CYPD3177](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-EZ-PD_BCR_Datasheet_USB_Type-C_Port_Controller_for_Power_Sinks-DataSheet-v03_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7d0d8da4017d0ee7ce9d70ad) USB-PD controller IC. The goal is to request 9V from a laptop and/or a PC computer's USB Type-C port whilst also establishing data communication. Current consumption is negligible, few tens of milliamps. Circuitry around CYPD3177 IC is identical to that presented in the datasheet.

The board works fine when connected to a fast charge adaptor, successfully negotiates 9 V. However, when connected to a computer's USB type-C port, it either fails to negotiate higher voltage and falls back to 5 V "safe power" (HP Probook 450 g6 - Thunderbolt 3/4) or fails to get any power whatsoever (Dell Vostro 5581 - USB 3.2 Superspeed with PD).

Both ports are capable of fast charging; they can charge a smartphone or similar devices without any problems. The board also works fine, as previously said, with a fast charge adaptor, or when the USB-PD controller IC is set such that it would request 5 V.

Is a PD-capable USB Type-C port of a laptop also capable of providing higher voltages, or is it limited to only 5 V with high currents? If the port is capable of providing high voltages, why does my board fail to negotiate for them?

Comment: Are there any specifications available for the USB port of the exact model of laptop you're using?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have experimented with HP Probook 450 G6 and Dell Vostro 5581, as well as two other devices that I cannot remember. I have attempted to get some information about the specs of the type c ports of these laptops, but I couldn't find anything related to PD.

Comment: There's nothing that says that it can't, but there's also nothing that says that it has to. Most are probably 5V only. Even for a device that speaks PD that's a valid profile.

Comment: @hobbs is there any way to know for sure?

Comment: I suppose you could find out what IC the computer uses to supply power to the USB port and check its capabilities on its datasheet. If it only says 5 V then that is definitely all it's going to supply; anything else might depend on the optional presence of additional circuitry.

Comment: Spec sheet or else hook up a PD device and poll the port to see what voltages it supports. That said, if you only need "negligible" current, it is a bad idea to depend on an optional voltage that most ports won't support. Instead, run off of 5v, skip PD entirely and generate your voltages on the device from 5v.

Comment: Laptop can provide only what it is capable of. If you can charge a laptop with 20V from USB power brick, it does not mean the laptop can output 20V or any other voltage than 5V. You have a USB PD controller, can you debug what the laptop communicates over PD?

Comment: @Justme Yes, I am fully aware of that. To debug the communication, I believe that I have to tap onto CC lines with a logic analyser, which I cannot do at the moment. I also don't have a dedicated PD analyser module either. And I have failed to find any way to do it from the computer side.

Comment: @user1850479 Unfortunately, I was attempting to avoid putting switching regulators on board.

Comment: I think this is a bad idea, but if you want an external power supply and it must be USB-C at 9v, then ship the device with an included power supply or hub that supports the specific voltage you need. Otherwise people are going to be very confused why the device doesn't work most of the time when they plug it in.

Comment: @user1850479 the device will be shipped with a computer of our preference, therefore it is possible for us to pick a computer which supports our needs. Although at this moment I am starting to doubt that such computers exist, at least widely enough to justify such design.

Comment: @aulven Using a specific laptop would be a fragile solution: if the laptop fails then the end-user would probably not be able to get a replacement easily.

Comment: They probably don't exist. Thunderbolt 3/4 certification requires at least 1 port source a minimum of 15 W, which is 5V 3A, so that's probably all you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've already got the boards and need to ship them as is, you can get hubs that split out the data from the USB-PD cheaply on Amazon:

[image: https://www.amazon.com/Anker-PowerExpand-Ethernet-Delivery-MacBook/dp/B08C9HZ5YT]

Then include whatever laptop you want.

If you haven't finalized your design yet, ditch the USB-PD as it is inappropriate for this application. PD lets you *request* higher voltage, but your application *demands* it, so it's incompatible with a large majority of USB ports.

Fortunately, if you really only need tens of milliamps, there are much better solutions. You can get a capacitive voltage doubler for half the price of the CYPD3177, which (for low current loads) will give you 10v from every USB port on Earth. Throw in an LDO and you've got a regulated 9v supply with lower noise then a USB rail and paid less for it.

Comment: This was my first idea as well, and even if I was able to get 9 V out of the computer, I still would provide such device as a backup. However, I am confused with these devices, because they appear to be designed to provide high power to the computer, not another device. Most of these don't mention PD on the other type-c port, and some explicitly state that it doesn't support PD. Would it work if I were to plug the type-c cable that supposed to plug into computer to my device, and the other type-c port to the computer?

Comment: @aulven I'm not familiar with that specific hub (just an example of a powered hub where you could ensure 9v), but I think you could plug the host into any USBC port on it. If not, there's lots of other products, some even with multiple PD ports.

Answer (score 1):

> Is a PD-capable USB Type-C port of a laptop also capable of providing
> higher voltages?

Not necessarily, it depends on particular design. In most practical cases a Type-C laptop port is not designed to provide more than +5V default power, usually set to 3A. I have never seen a laptop that has a "charging port" capable of supplying elevated voltages, even on a monster-size "gaming laptops". The ports can take elevated voltages, but not supply.

Even then, when running on battery alone, the port might dynamically switch to 1.5A (or disable another USB-C port) if power management firmware determines that the system running power plus USB supplied power exceeds battery capability. If running with AC-DC adapter, the policy might be different. In any case it depends on design, and port capabilities should be clearly stated in device user manual.

And for your particular application your best bet is to use a pump-up converter as user1850479 suggested.